# Determine the minimum number of coin-weighings

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, co.combinatorics, it.information-theory, randomized-algorithms

In the paper [On two problems of information theory](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1963-12.pdf),  Erdõs and Rényi give lower bounds on the minimum number of weighings one must do to determine the number of false coins in a set of $n$ coins.

More formally:

> The false coins have a smaller weight than the right coins; the
>   weights $a$ and $b < a$ of both the right and false coins are known. A
>   scale is given by means of which any number $\leq n$ of coins can be
>   weighed together. Thus if we select an arbitrary subset of the coins
>   and put them together on the scale, then the scale shows us the total
>   weight of these coins, from which it is easy to compute the number of
>   false coins among those weighed. The question is what is the minimal
>   number, $A(n)$ of weighings by means of which the right and false coins
>   can be separated?

The trivial lower bound they initially provide is:

$n / \log_2 (n + 1)$.

This isn't hard to see why through various information-theoretic or combinatorial arguments. The problem is how to construct such sets to do these weighings? Are there algorithms that utilize a constructive proof to achieve these lower bounds without relying on randomness? Are there randomized algorithms that achieve these bounds?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a brief look at [this paper](http://colt2009.cs.mcgill.ca/papers/004.pdf), and it appears that the answer to your question is yes (that is - no need for randomization). Also, the Introduction section surveys previous algorithms, information theoretic lower bounds and so on.

Comment: This is Nader H. Bshouty, _Optimal algorithms for the coin weighing problem with a spring scale_, Conference on Learning Theory 2009.  http://colt2009.cs.mcgill.ca/papers/004.pdf